# How to add animations to slick sync slider

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, slick.js

I am using slick slider which has a functionality similar to [this](https://codepen.io/paulfleury/pen/pvvzGx) [Slick sync slider]. I am unable to add any animations to it. I want the image to appear from the left and text to appear from the right like [this-second slide](https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/WvoRQo).

I tried adding animate.css and using data-animated="fadeInLeft", but that is loading all the slides at the same time and above all, it is not serving the purpose.

Is there an option where i can add animation using JS or CSS?

```js
$('.slider-quote-block').slick({ 
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     arrows: false,
     fade: true,
     asNavFor: '.slider-image-block' 
 });
 $('.slider-image-block').slick({
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     asNavFor: '.slider-quote-block',
     dots: false
    });
```

```css
.testimonial {
 img {
  position:relative;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 1;
  h5 {
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 0px 38px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 22px;
   font-family: $font-stack;
   &:last-child {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: $font-arial;
    padding-left:15px;
    &:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     background-color: $cabaret;
           top: -5px;
        left: -13px;
        height: 35px;
        width: 3px;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
.slider-image-block, .slider-quote-block {
 width:50%;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="testimonial clearfix">
      <!--image-->
      <div class="slider-image-block">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <img src="images/testimonial1.png" alt="slider-image 1">
          <figcaption><h5>name</h5><h5>designation</h5></figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <img src="images/testimonial1.png" alt="slider-image 2">
          <figcaption><h5>name</h5><h5>designation</h5></figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <img src="images/testimonial1.png" alt="slider-image 3">
           <figcaption><h5>name</h5><h5>designation</h5></figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <img src="images/testimonial1.png" alt="slider-image 4">
           <figcaption><h5>name</h5><h5>designation</h5></figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <img src="images/testimonial1.png" alt="slider-image 5">
          <figcaption><h5>name</h5><h5>designation</h5></figcaption>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--quote-->
      <div class="slider-quote-block">
        <div class="blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p> 
        </div>
      </div>     
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in option in Slick to use a custom animation or transition. You could open an issue about this, although I am not sure if the author wants to support this.

Anyway, I found that if you really want to use Slick *and* want to have custom transitions, you can do it using a bit of a hack. I have cooked up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fa0s7e7/1/) that demonstrates this. Hopefully this is what you wanted?

To make it so that part of a slide comes in from one side and part from the other side, I have used the options in Slick to step two slides at a time. In the custom event listener, these two slides are then given different animations to achieve the effect you are looking for.

The relevant code is the event listener in the following.

```
var slides = $('.slide');
$('.slick').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  speed: 0 // hack to disable Slick transitions
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  slides.removeClass('slideInLeft slideInRight');
  // use custom transition
  slides.eq(nextSlide).addClass('slideInLeft');
  slides.eq(nextSlide + 1).addClass('slideInRight');
});
```

It is a combination of disabling Slick transitions by setting the speed to 0 and applying a custom transition in the event listener. AFAIK, there is currently no way to disable transitions in a nicer way, but that would of course be preferable. Another option would be to not use Slick at all, but I leave that up to you to decide.

**EDIT:** Changing the animation speed ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fa0s7e7/2/)) and using a synced slider ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fa0s7e7/3/)) can also be done, per request in comments. To make the slides appear as one slide in the navigation slider, some more CSS can be used ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fa0s7e7/4/)).

Comment: The look is matching to an extent. I want the speed to be more and moreover, you have done this for a single slider. It will throw an error when i will try to implement this code on a sync slider. Can you suggest a way how i can add this transition to a slick sync slider?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include links to demos of what you asked for. Changing the animation speed is a matter of some CSS, when using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Using a synced slider did not throw any errors for me, I may have missed something?